# change ImageView src in Kotlin

Tags: xml, flutter, kotlin, imageview, resources

I am trying to change my home widget ImageView in Kotlin and define my resources like this. but nothing show to me.By the way, I work with Flutter and not familiar with Kotlin so much

the xml file is :

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/defaultcond"
    />
```

the WidgetProvider.kt is :

```
    val ivCond = widgetData.getString("ivCond","defaultcond")
    var ivId = "$ivCond"
    val drawableId: Int = context.getResources().getIdentifier(ivId, null, null)
    setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView,drawableId)
```

all images are inside the res/drawable folder.

and the code inside the future function is :

```
    await HomeWidget.saveWidgetData(
    'ivCond', code(widget.weather.currentWeather!.weathercode));
```

I search a lot and try to fix this but any changes I got an error the code that found for change the resource of ImageView not work fine for me.

I try to fix this by searching but all the codes that others send to fix problem not work for me and shows error for Kotlin coding.

Comment: I don't know but I think this line code drawableId has nothing or has wrong value       
`val drawableId: Int = context.getResources().getIdentifier(ivId, null, null)`

Comment: I use println to get output of drawableId and anytime I got `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your Time I figure out the problem and solve that with refractor this line

`val drawableId: Int = context.getResources().getIdentifier(ivId, "drawable", context.getPackageName())`

I guessed that the problem was from this part.
‌Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
build.gradle(Module)
android{
....
buildFeatures{
viewBinding true
   }
}
```

for me this works

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var _binding ActivityMainBinding?=null
private val binding
get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    binding.apply{
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image)
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply can you help me how define the myImageView in kotlin. I mean how use findViewById

Comment: Unfortunately I got this error `Unresolved reference: findViewById`

Comment: You better use view binding. let's not mess with findviewbyid